# Tomcat 7 fails to start due to JDWP syntax error on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, tomcat7, startup

I am trying to get Tomcat 7 to run on my development machine at work. I have come across a really bizarre problem that I have never seen before.

When I run catalina `run` (as well as `start`), I get the following:

```
c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin>catalina run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
Using CLASSPATH:       "c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin\bootstrap.jar;c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin\tomcat
-juli.jar"
ERROR: JDWP option syntax error: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\endorsed -classpath c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin\bootst
rap.jar;c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin\tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59 -Dcatali
na.home=c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59 -Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\temp org.apache.catalina.st
artup.Bootstrap  start

c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin>
```

As you can see, we didn't ask it to use JDWP at all. I checked catalina.bat, and this code path should not even be executed, correct?

I have my JAVA_HOME set, and I've played with various configurations of JRE_HOME and so on.

This is so bizarre to me. How can I get Tomcat 7 to start?

EDIT:

```
c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin>echo %JPDA_OPTS%
%JPDA_OPTS%

c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin>
```

Comment: Check all of your environment variables.  For example, do you have a "-agentlib" option specification in `%JAVA_OPTS%`?

Comment: Nope. There is some JAVA_OPTS defined, but it is just a variable that our web application uses: `-Dapp.home=c:\app`. That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are useing powershell, use cmd instead.

Comment: I am using cmd actually. This is just basic install of windows 7

Comment: what is teh result of echo %JPDA_OPTS%?

Comment: I am not at work now, but I suspect it's exactly what is inside `catalina.bat` is setting it to.

Comment: adjuke, well sry i was experiencing a similiar problem once, and pwoershell was the source. feel free to downvote